# When the anticipated sample size is not reached in a clinical trial

Tags: sample-size, statistical-power, clinical-trials

How to justify precisely a situation where the expected sample size is not reached?

For example, the sample size for our study protocol was determined on the basis of a fixed statistical power of 80%. We needed around 200 patients but practically, only the data of 70 patients could be gathered.

Thanks

Comment: That is not the right usage for the term NNT which is the reciprocal of a risk difference.  Please edit the title and the text.

Comment: Thank you and appreciate your comment. Isn’t NNT the minimum number of patients to be included in a study in order to preserve a given statistical power?

Comment: No, NNT is the number of patients needed to be treated to save one life.

Comment: Precisely what aspect of this study do you wish to justify and what was the outcome?

Comment: I got it, thank you. The post has been edited accordingly.

Comment: The study assess the impact of a self-rehabilitation program on limitations of patients with spastic hemiparesis following stroke. The primary outcome variable is the percentage of patients attaining their primary treatment goal determined by the Goal Attainment Scaling (GAS). The information gathered during each follow-up visit are represented as a binary variables (Was the primary treatment goal achieved? Yes/No). As the statistical power of at least 80% is not met, I would like to explain the impact this can have on the interpretation of the results of statistical analysis.

Comment: Did you find an effect or not find an effect?